# Parsing multipart/mixed responses with Node.js and axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, get, multipart

I've trying to parse a multipart/mixed response with (1) JSON and (2) .zip file.

I've been using Axios to GET the response, no problem there. I've seen npm packages like [meros](https://www.npmjs.com/package/meros) and [multipart-mixed-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multipart-mixed-parser) but both just returned an empty array.

the response looks like

```
--Boundary_137_1895017408_1627074248456
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "createdDate" : "2021-07-22T01:46:05.149+0000",
   more JSON...
}

--Boundary_137_1895017408_1627074248456
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="347b3bd1-e6e3-49a0-928d-9956df5c5af11671844264911435718.tmp"; modification-date="Fri, 23 Jul 2021 21:04:08 GMT"; size=620991; name="attachments.zip"

binary data here ...

--Boundary_137_1895017408_1627074248456--
```

```js
    async function eManGet (mtn, zipPath) {
      try {
        mtn = mtn.toUpperCase()
        if (zipPath) {
          const res = eManAPI.get({
            url: `/emanifest/manifest/${mtn}/attachments`,
            headers: {
              Accept: 'multipart/mixed'
            }
          })
          return res
        } else {
         ...
        }
        // console.log(res.data)
      } catch (error) {
       ...
      }
    }
```

The [package I want to use this for is here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/haztrak)

If you've faced this problem before, what package(s) did you use?

Comment: surely someone's dealt with this problem before

Comment: Have you found a solution without writing a parser yourself ?

Comment: I figured someone would've done this before as well. I've found some one-off npm packages for other people's personal use but they're situation specific and not maintained. If y'all are interested, please upvote this question so we can get more people interested.

Answer (score 0):

The [dicer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dicer) npm package does the job pretty well. You'll have to extract the boudary from headers yourself tho.

Answer (score 0):

## How to send multipart/mixed with axios

There is example of source code with `request`

```
const messages = body[endpoint].map(function (m) {
    return {
        'Content-Type': 'application/http',
        body: 'GET ' + api + '/gmail/v1/users/me/' + endpoint + '/' + m.id + query + '\n'
    }
})

const r = request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: api + '/batch/gmail/v1',
    multipart: messages,
    timeout: opts.timeout,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + key,
        'content-type': 'multipart/mixed'
    }
})
```

from this library

https://github.com/SpiderStrategies/node-gmail-api

To solve this problem I used request catcher and wrote the following tests:

```
it('request catcher of request', () => {
  const catcher = 'https://pl.requestcatcher.com/';

  const messages = [1,2,3].map(function (index:number) {
    return {
      'Content-Type': 'application/http',
      body: 'GET ' + `/gmail/v1/users/me/${index}\n`
    }
  })

  const r = request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: catcher,
    multipart: messages,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer KEY',
      'content-type': 'multipart/mixed'
    }
  })

  expect(r).toBeNull();
})
```

and saw the following request on catcher:

[image]

For axios there is not ready answer in all internet. This is my research:

> You can use a FormData object in the browser. In Node.js the feature isn't supported yet by axios (see #789).

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/803

> [RFC2388] suggested that multiple files for a single form field be
> transmitted using a nested "multipart/mixed" part.  This usage is
> deprecated.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7578

> info how to do it in request ( that is also depreciated )

https://github.com/request/request#multipartrelated

> Function for generation boundary

https://github.com/form-data/form-data/blob/53adbd81e9bde27007b28083068f2fc8272614dc/lib/form_data.js#L347

So we can send multipart/mixed by this code

```
  it('request catcher of axios', () => {
    const catcher = 'https://pl.requestcatcher.com/';

    const r = axios.post(catcher, `--3e50fc2b-7a5c-4565-99f2-1628010018be
Content-Type: application/http

GET /gmail/v1/users/me/1

--3e50fc2b-7a5c-4565-99f2-1628010018be
Content-Type: application/http

GET /gmail/v1/users/me/2

--3e50fc2b-7a5c-4565-99f2-1628010018be
Content-Type: application/http

GET /gmail/v1/users/me/3

--3e50fc2b-7a5c-4565-99f2-1628010018be--`,{
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer KEY',
        'content-type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary=3e50fc2b-7a5c-4565-99f2-1628010018be'
      }
    })

    expect(r).not.toBeNull();

  })
```

and now oly generation of boundary is problem to solve. Lets check differences between `multipart/mixed` and and `multipart/form-data` bounduaries.

This is exmple of bounduary from form-data package:

```
--------------------------942880057551350107765038
```

and this is from mixed (from request):

```
--3e50fc2b-7a5c-4565-99f2-1628010018be
```

and this is proper RFC

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

so we can use this code

```
> `--${crypto.randomUUID()}`
'--7784084f-e129-44ea-aa64-8f480a26c75f'
```

And this is code that sends mutipart/mixed by axios

```
    it('request catcher of axios', () => {
        const catcher = 'https://pl.requestcatcher.com/';

        interface SingleMultipartMixedMessage {
            'Content-Type': string,
            body: string
        }

        const messages = [1, 2, 3].map(function (index: number) {
            return {
                'Content-Type': 'application/http',
                body: 'GET ' + `/gmail/v1/users/me/${index}\n`
            }
        })

        const boundary = `--${crypto.randomUUID()}`

        const body = messages.reduce((p: string, n: SingleMultipartMixedMessage) => {
            return p + `\nContent-Type: ${n['Content-Type']}\n\n${n.body}\n${boundary}`
        }, boundary)

        const r = axios.post(catcher, body, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer KEY',
                'content-type': `multipart/mixed; boundary=${boundary.replace(/^--/, '')}`
            }
        })

        expect(r).not.toBeNull();

    })
```

and comparison of requests caught by caught between reference implementation [ request ] and our code [ axios ]

[image]

## How to parse multipart mixed

1. Get boundary from content-type header
2. Add `--` before it
3. Split body by this boundary
4. Any part split by double `\n`
5. Parse any pair of headers and data individually